# Double integral - changing order of integration

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, definite-integrals

I am trying to change the order of integration of the following double integral $$\int _0^{2a} dx\int _{\sqrt{2ax-x^2}}^{\sqrt{4ax}} f(x,y) \ dy .$$ (a>0)

I've sketched the domain but am struggling to change it from type 1 domain to type 2 domain. Any help?

[image]

I've attached an image of the geometry of the domain and I've shaded it. (Well the image shows the case when a=1.)

Comment: I haven't encountered the terms "Type 1 domain" and "Type 2 domain"... would you mind defining these. Also, perhaps sharing a photo of your sketch would help us evaluate your work.

Answer (score 1):

Let $y=\sqrt{4ax}$ ($0\le x\le 2a$) and then $x=\frac{y^2}{4a}$. Let $y=\sqrt{2ax-x^2}$ ($0\le x\le 2a$) and then
$$ x=a\pm\sqrt{a^2-y^2}. $$ 
Thus the area is divided into three parts:

(1). $\frac{y^2}{4a}\le x\le a-\sqrt{a^2-y^2}, 0\le y\le a$;

(2). $a+\sqrt{a^2-y^2}\le x\le 2a, 0\le y\le a$;

(3). $\frac{y^2}{4a}\le x\le 2a, a\le y\le 2\sqrt 2a$.

So
\begin{eqnarray}
&&\int _0^{2a} dx\int _{\sqrt{2ax-x^2}}^{\sqrt{4ax}} f(x,y) \ dy\\
&=&\int _0^{a} dy\int _{\frac{y^2}{4a}}^{a-\sqrt{a^2-y^2}} f(x,y) \ dx+\int _0^{a} dy\int^{2a}_{a+\sqrt{a^2-y^2}} f(x,y)dx+\int_a^{2\sqrt2a} dy\int^{2a}_{\frac{y^2}{4a}} f(x,y) \ dx.
\end{eqnarray}

Comment: Is there no way of combining his into a single integral. This is what I got buy just the way the question is worded would seem like you can. But it doesn't look like you can. Guess this is what the question meant if not.

Comment: @Ben, I doubt it is possible.

Comment: Did you make a mistake in your very last integral. Should the upper y limit be $2\sqrt 2 a $ not $2a$?

Comment: @Ben, Yes, you are right.

Answer (score 1):

I hope it can help you

[image]

$1)\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\int_{y=a}^{y=\sqrt{8}a} (\int_{x=\frac{y^2}{4a}}^{x=2a}f(x,y)\, dx)\,dy$

$\color{lime}{2)}\,\,\,\,\int_{y=0}^{y=a} (\int_{x=\frac{y^2}{4a}}^{x=a-\sqrt{a^2-y^2}}f(x,y)\, dx)\,dy$

$\color{#f8f}{3)}\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\int_{y=0}^{y=a} (\int_{x=a+\sqrt{a^2-y^2}}^{x=2a}f(x,y)\, dx)\,dy$

---

$\int _0^{2a} dx\int _{\sqrt{2ax-x^2}}^{\sqrt{4ax}} f(x,y) \ dy$

$=\int_{y=a}^{y=\sqrt{8}a} (\int_{x=\frac{y^2}{4a}}^{x=2a}f(x,y)\, dx)\,dy+\int_{y=0}^{y=a} (\int_{x=\frac{y^2}{4a}}^{x=a-\sqrt{a^2-y^2}}f(x,y)\, dx)\,dy+\int_{y=0}^{y=a} (\int_{x=a+\sqrt{a^2-y^2}}^{x=2a}f(x,y)\, dx)\,dy$

Answer (score 0):

Here is what the domain  looks like with $a=1$:

[image]

You cannot  switch the order of integration: the bounds are different when for example $y=1/2$ and $y=2$.

What is the $f(x,y)$ explicitly?

Comment: I don't have $f(x,y)$ explicitly - only know that it is continuous. I have a question asking me to sketch the domain and to use the sketch to change the order of integration - I'm aware that you can't just switch the order.